# PowerShell: how to sort based on group?

Tags: sorting, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a .csv file like this (; as a delimiter):

```
Group1; User_A
Group1; User_B
Group2; User_A
Group2; User_D
Group2; User_C
```

where first column is AD group and second column is users. How can I sort users in groups? I tried something like

```
$header = "Group", "User"
Import-Csv "C:\temp\users.csv" -Header $header -Delimiter ";" | Sort-Object
```

But produces

```
Group                                                                   User                                                                   
-----                                                                   ----                                                                   
Group2                                                                  User_D                                                                 
Group2                                                                  User_C                                                                 
Group2                                                                  User_A                                                                 
Group1                                                                  User_A                                                                 
Group1                                                                  User_B
```

which is not correct.

Comment: Why down vote, what is wrong with this question?

Comment: I'm guessing the down votes are because you could have found the answer by reading `help Sort-Object`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell `Sort-Object` how you want to sort the objects:

```
Import-Csv "C:\temp\users.csv" -Header $header -Delimiter ";" | Sort-Object Group, User
```